# Jenkins - Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, aapt2

I am trying to work with Jenkins however I cannot build the apk with it as I am having issue with AAPT2 and Gradle.

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugResources'.
> Multiple task action failures occurred:
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
      > Android resource compilation failed
        ERROR:C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\b478eb984dbbd1317dab9bfd9689b3aa\transformed\appcompat-1.3.0\res\drawable-hdpi-v4\abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png: AAPT: error: file not found.
            
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
      > Android resource compilation failed
        ERROR:C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\b478eb984dbbd1317dab9bfd9689b3aa\transformed\appcompat-1.3.0\res\drawable-xhdpi-v4\abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png: AAPT: error: file not found.
            
   > A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.res.Aapt2CompileRunnable
      > Android resource compilation failed
        ERROR:C:\Windows\System32\config\systemprofile\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\b478eb984dbbd1317dab9bfd9689b3aa\transformed\appcompat-1.3.0\res\drawable-mdpi-v4\abc_list_divider_mtrl_alpha.9.png: AAPT: error: file not found.
```

I already read tons of SO question that may share same issue to my case saying that it has something to do with the file path being too long but I still cannot find any solution.

**UPDATE**

I tried to change Android Studio Gradle home similar to what Jenkins is using and received similar error which indicates that it may really have something to do with long file path.

I think the final question will be how to change Jenkins Gradle Home?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to replace  `\` with `\\` if you are giving path with jenkins in Windows.
May be if file path is too huge or that is the root cause  you can try mounting the directory to a short path

**EDIT** : Based on your modified question :
Open Jenkins dashboard. Navigate to `Manage Jenkins-> Configure System`. Under the `Global properties section` add another `environment variable` named `GRADLE_USER_HOME` as shown below.
[image]

Comment: I update my question, it really has something to do with Gradle home path. Unfortunately I am new to Jenkins and I do not know how to change its Gradle home path just like I can easily change it in Android Studio.

Comment: @BitwiseDEVS : I have added the answer with the method for adding Gradle home path

Comment: Yes I already managed to settle this a few hours ago as I recheck the Jenkins configuration page after I rest and cleared my mind, however you still did an effort attempting to help me so I will mark yours as an answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this exact issue, but unfortunately changing the GRADLE_USER_HOME environment variable did not help, as aapt2 appeared to ignore the change and still used Windows/system32/... for the cache location.

The problem was how I was running Jenkins as a service. In the service.msc settings, it was set to Log On as a Local System account, which set the USER_HOME variables to C:\Windows\System32. Because of this, the reason the error said that the file did not exist was because Jenkins/gradle did not have access to the System32 folder.

My fix was to change the log on method to 'This account', then enter a user account so Jenkins wasn't logged on as system anymore.

[image: Jenkins Log On window]

Comment: I had this exact problem - thank you!